# Get Axis of the 3D object by using three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to get axis from a Three-Dimensional objects in three js?
My code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>three Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!Detector.webgl) {
            Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        }
        var container;
        var scene, renderer, camera, cameraTarget;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            var img_width = 250;
            var img_height = 300;
            var viewAngle = 45;
            var aspectRatio = img_width / img_height;
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewAngle, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(300, 450, 300);
            cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x72645b, 2, 15);

            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            light.position.set(0, 300, 300);
            scene.add(light);

            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555));

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
            renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
            renderer.setSize(img_width, img_height);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var stl_loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            stl_loader.load("Bird_cage.stl", function (geometry) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200});
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.position.set(0, -0.25, 0.6);
                mesh.rotation.set(0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
                mesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

                scene.add(mesh);
            });
        }


        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }

        function render()
        {
            var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005
            camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 3;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 300;
            camera.lookAt(cameraTarget);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }



    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/80ozg046/

**Using this html.I load stl file and convert it into three dimensional objects by using thee js.Now ,What is the problem is,I want to  find X-Axis,Y-Axis and Z-Axis value.
If some suggestion to solve this problem,I must be thankful to them.**

Comment: what do you mean `get X-Axis`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with X-Axis, Y-Axis and Z-Axis. Maybe it'll be helpful if you explain what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @mrdoob My Problem is While i loading large objects as stl files such as towers.I use scale function (ie) mesh.scale.set to scale down the object.But when i load small objects such as cage,box.It scales down further and display very smaller mesh.I want to show large object stl files as well small object stl files in similar width and height.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now the original boundingBox shows null but there's is a somewhat undocumented Helper now I think.

```
     var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(mesh, 0xff0000);
    helper.update();
    // If you want a visible bounding box
    scene.add(helper);
    // If you just want the numbers
    console.log(helper.box.min);
    console.log(helper.box.max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MasterJames/m67v5bz7/2/

Then you can take a ratio of the two BIG and small objects you want to match up before you scale.

Comment: I think this answer is more  useful to me.Thanks @Master james

Comment: Newer BoxHelper had some missing features I deleted from the original http://jsfiddle.net/MasterJames/m67v5bz7/11/